# Insert nested stdClass into database

Tags: php

I have been working on a project to automatic fetch information from a client page. Its basically a function that call a bunch of other functions and arrange the information in an stdClass Object. I thought I was clever and made it "searchable" but I have encountered some small problems.

Here is an example of the output:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [ud] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [svenska] => Uddev
                    [engelska] => uddev
                )

            [biografer] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [namn] => Drottning. Uddev
                            [id] => 196
                            [salonger] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [salong] => Vag 1
                                            [platser] => 100 platser
                                            [ljud] => SOU
                                        )

                                    [1] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [salong] => Vag 2
                                            [platser] => 100 platser
                                            [ljud] => SOU
                                        )

                                    [2] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [salong] => Vag 3
                                            [platser] => 60 platser
                                            [ljud] => SOU
                                        )

                                    [3] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [salong] => Vag 4
                                            [platser] => 50 platser
                                            [ljud] => SOU
                                        )

                                    [4] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [salong] => Vag 5
                                            [platser] => 50 platser
                                            [ljud] => DOLBY
                                        )

                                    [5] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [salong] => Vag 6
                                            [platser] => 34 platser
                                            [ljud] => 
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )
    [ma] => stdClass Object
        (
...... And the following object
```

As you can see, the index (or is it the key) for the first object is `ud`.

I thought that i could do something like this:

```
$test = $crawler->fetchAllArray();

foreach ($test as $key => $value) {
    if($key == 'ud'){
        foreach ($value->{ud} as $child => $ud) { # line 295
            echo "id: $key" . ", name: $ud->name->svenska";
        }
    }
}
```

And that would generate `id: ud, name: Uddev`, but I receive the following error:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant ud - assumed 'ud' in test.php on
>   line 295
>
> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$ud in test.php on line 295
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in test.php on line
>   295

How do I properly echo the information from a specific object?

Comment: Before using property you can check it with `isset` or `property_exists`. like isset($value->ud)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have this?

```
$value->{ud}
```

You should be accessing the nested object as:

```
$value
```

or even as

```
$test->ud
```

directly.

And what's the second foreach for? Not particularly clear what you want to accomplish, but you could do:

```
foreach ($test as $key => $value) {
    if($key == 'ud'){
          echo "id: $key" . ", name: ".  $value->name->svenska;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright, still receiving `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$ud` when changed to above.

Comment: Yup, now I see you are mixing up your objects. "ud" is a property for $test, which is represented by $value inside your `foreach`. See updated answer.

Comment: Of course thats how it works, thanks for your help! =)